# cfenv rounding behaviour in C

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding

`cfenv` provides API to control rounding mode for floating point operations in C. In particular, possible control flags include `FE_DOWNWARD` and `FE_UPWARD` which are responsible for rounding towards smaller or greater value respectively.

However, I'm confused if these flags affect the individual floating point operations or expression as a whole. As an example let:

```
fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
double res = c - a * tanh(b);
```

If the flag `FE_UPWARD` affect expression as a whole, then `res` would contain a sound upper bound of `c - a * tanh(b)`. If, however, it affects individual floating point operations then `a * tanh(b)` will be evaluated first (and maximized) and `res` is not guaranteed to contain an upper bound anymore.

Does the flag `FE_UPWARD` give the upper bound of the whole floating point expression or does it only gives upper bound of the individual floating point operations?

Comment: Why don't you just check what the generated assembly code does?

Comment: `cfenv` is the C++ name of the header for floating-point environment facilities. The C name is `fenv.h`.

Answer (score 3):

The floating-point rounding mode, if it is supported in a C implementation, affects individual operations. This may include library routines—ideally, it should include library routines, but support for rounding modes in math libraries is often lacking.

The floating-point rounding mode does not operate globally on expressions your program computes. Typically, the compiler has no way of analyzing or modifying your expressions to make that work.